# Почему PWA ломает работу сайта?

Tags: javascript, кэширование, service-worker

Начал изучение Progresive web application. При внедрении на сайт всё шло отлично.

1. Зарегистрировал воркеров:

   ```
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
       window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
           // Registration was successful
           console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: 
   ', registration.scope);
       }, function(err) {
           // registration failed :(
           console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
       });
   });
   }
   ```
2. Установил и активировал заполнение кеша через файл sw.js:

   ```
   self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
   e.waitUntil(
       //Create new cache
       caches.open('v2').then(function(cache) {
           return cache.addAll([
               '/', ...,
           ]);
       })
   );
   });

   self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
   event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
       // caches.match() always resolves
       // but in case of success response will have value
       if (response !== undefined) {
           return response;
       } else {
           return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
               // response may be used only once
               // we need to save clone to put one copy in cache
               // and serve second one
               let responseClone = response.clone();

               caches.open('v2').then(function (cache) {
                   cache.put(event.request, responseClone);
               });
               return response;
           });
       }
   }));
   });
   ```

После всех махинаций при добавлении сайта со смартфона на главный экран всё работает отлично. Сначала в кеш загружается главная страница с нужными файлами, после чего при переходе на другие страницы они тоже попадают в кеш и сайт работает оффлайн.

Проблема в следующем: PWA сломало стабильную работу сайта. Я не могу на нем банально авторизоваться. При этом в консоли возникают следующие ошибки: (браузер Chrome)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
С чем это может быть связано и что я не учел?